# Is there a notion analogous to separability but requiring definable rather than countable sets?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, foundations, lattice-theory, lambda-calculus

Among models of $\lambda$-calculus, some like the Bohm tree model have the property that every element is a directed sup of definable elements, whereas others like the $D_\infty$ and $P(\omega)$ models contain "extra" elements (e.g. step functions) that are not sups of sets of $\lambda$-definable elements.

Among models of the real numbers, standard models have the property that every element is a sup of a set of rational (0,1,+,-,*,/-definable) points, whereas nonstandard models can contain "extra"  elements like infinitesimals.

Does this property have a common name? A model is ___ if every element is a sup of a set of definable elements, for a give notion of definability.

Related properties of similar grammatical form:

- *separability* of a metric space
- *algebraicity* of a continuous lattice
- *completeness* of a partial order or semilattice
- *standardness* of a model of the reals
- *full-abstraction* of model of a programming language

Comment: Why not just "definability"? These matters are related to the concept of "sequentiality" as well. [This light article by Curien](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1277.68120) might help.

Comment: People in higher-order computability also say "recursive in f, g..." for an element definable by abstractions, applications, initial functions and fixpoints over extra (e.g. parallel) elements f, g...

Comment: @Basil Thanks for the reference. Here are three "definability"-like properties: a model is definable if it can be constructed in some language; a model is "definably inhabited" if each of its elements is definable (e.g. the rationals or the algebraic reals, depending on language); and a model is "definably compact" if each of its elements is a sup of definable elements (e.g. the standard reals or the Bohm tree model). It is this last property I am interested in.

Comment: You're asking that the finite or compact elements of the model be definable. This is one of the requirements for **full abstraction**; maybe Basil's suggested article by Curien might help you with this.  Unfortunately, a lot of the theoretical computer scientists who might have answered this question have now left MathOverflow for another site.

Comment: Besides containing a spelling mistake, your title is misleading about your question.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Thanks, I changed 'compactness' to 'separability' in title and gave an example in Real numbers. I'm struggling to frame the question without tying too closely to a single domain.